# Remove/delete values in a column SQL

Tags: sql

I am very new to using SQL and require help.
I have a table containing comma in the values

```
+-------------------+
|      Sample       |
+-------------------+
| sdferewr,yyuyuy   |
| q45345,ty67rt     |
| wererert,rtyrtytr |
| werr,ytuytu       |
+-------------------+
```

I would want to delete/remove the values after the comma(,) and keep only those values before it.
Output required.

```
+----------+
|  Sample  |
+----------+
| sdferewr |
| q45345   |
| wererert |
| werr     |
+----------+
```

How would I be able to do this in SQL? please help

Comment: Do you already have data like that or you're building something brand new?

Comment: this is the data that is already available. And I want to remove the commas in them as they have been included by mistake in the data. And the values before the commas are the actual values that is required.

Comment: Please _move away_ from this data model ASAP.  SQL delete is a row-based concept, where the smallest unit of deletion is an entire row, not a value in a CSV string.  Don't store CSV if you can avoid it.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and string functions are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the table name is "TABLE_NAME" and the field name is "sample". Then

```
update TABLE_NAME set sample=SUBSTRING_INDEX(`sample`, ',', 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. With the inputs provided, I was able to get the desired output. I used this code: UPDATE table1
SET columnname = SUBSTRING(columnname,1,CHARINDEX(',', columnaname, 1)-1)
where columnname like '%,%'

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to do that is

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column = substring(column for position('',' in column))
WHERE condition;
```

`position(',' in column)` will return the position of the comma  and `substring(column for n)` returns the first n characters

Comment: Thank you. With the inputs provided, I was able to get the desired output. I used this code: UPDATE table1
SET columnname = SUBSTRING(columnname,1,CHARINDEX(',', columnaname, 1)-1)
where columnname like '%,%'